# radio buttons unable to select in UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am trying to select radio button but somehow they not showing up in UI side. I have verified that buttons can be pressed as it calls a function on click but UI not showing any selection.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="flagInfo in availableList">
    <input type="radio" name="flag" id="{{flagInfo.flagName}}" value="{{flagInfo.flagName}}" data-ng-click="selection(flagInfo.flagName)" />
    <span class="checkbox-label">
        <label for="{{flagInfo.flagName}}">{{flagInfo.translation}}</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: add ng-model="radioModel" to your input type radio

Answer (score 2):

Created snipet for you. you have missed ng-model in your code.

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
$scope.radioList={
'flagName':'abc'
}
    $scope.availableList =  [{
        'flagName':'abc',
        'id':1
    },{
        'flagName':'def',
        'id':2
    },{
        'flagName':'ghi',
        'id':3
    },{
        'flagName':'jkl',
        'id':4
    }];
  $scope.radioChange=function(radval){
    console.log(radval);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="flagInfo in availableList">
    <input type="radio" name="flag" id="{{flagInfo.flagName}}" value="{{flagInfo.flagName}}"  ng-model="radioList.flagName" ng-change="radioChange(radioList.flagName)" />
    <span class="checkbox-label">
        <label for="{{flagInfo.flagName}}">{{flagInfo.flagName}}</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
  Selected Radio : {{radioList.flagName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry even after using ng-model="flagInfo.flagName" change not reflect in a  UI side.